# Intercités de Nuit “Espace Privatif" with 2nd class Interrail?

Tags: trains, france, night-transport

The French Intercites de Nuit offer the option to book *Espace Privatif* for a supplement.  It is available when booking at least one ticket in first class or at least four in second class.  For example, a full compartment for two people in first starts at €170 (2*€60 for the tickets, €50 supplement).  See also *[How to book entire compartments on French night trains?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/16691/2509)*.

What are the rules and prices when travelling with 2 people on a *2nd class Interrail*?  Is it possible to pay for a 1st class upgrade, or would we need to pay the full €170 or upgrade to a 1st class Interail completely?

Comment: The option to upgrade to a first class ticket from a second class ticket depends on the original second class ticket fare (is it cancelable/exchangeable).

Comment: @audionuma In this case, the original “ticket” would be Interrail + reservations, which are all cancelable and exchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the only way to book this service (at least online) is to do it while you are booking your tickets (as it checks that the train you are booking on does offer this service). I don't see an alternative to canceling your second class ticket and book some fresh first class ones, adding the private space option. Or buying four second class tickets and also opting for the private space (whichever option is cheaper).

Things may be different if you can go to a booking office (in a train station for example).

Comment: I don't think buying four reservations for two (Interrail) tickets is accepted/possible.  I will ask the agency through which I plan to book the reservations.  A lot of reservations cannot be booked online anyway, so the non-availability of this option online doesn't mean the option doesn't exist at all.